# iOS BLE peripheral scanning when app in background or phone is in lock state

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently working with an app in which needs countinues background scanning for peripheral. We need to allow the duplication key while initialising the scanning for the peripheral.

I had written a sample app for experimenting about this. I have enabled the background capabilities in my app for finite sate running.I found that the number of hits in discover peripheral delegate method is very less when app is background. Even less when phone is in lock state. And the number of hits is different at different time for same app state. Also we noted a problem in initiating connection when phone is in lock screen or app is in background.

Is this an expected behaviour? Did I miss anything?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that:

> When your iOS app is in the background or in a suspended state, its Bluetooth
> related capabilities are affected. […] Even when you declare one or both of [the background execution modes, certain Bluetooth tasks operate differently while your app is in the background. You want to take these differences into account when designing your app.
>
> Even apps that support background processing may be terminated by the system at any time to free up memory for the current foreground app. As of iOS 7, Core Bluetooth supports saving state information for central and peripheral manager objects and restoring that state at app launch time. You can use this feature to support long-term actions involving Bluetooth devices. – [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW6)

> If all apps that are scanning for peripherals are in the background, the interval at which your central device scans for advertising packets increases. As a result, it may take longer to discover an advertising peripheral. — [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1)

Your app is able to scan when in background when declaring it in the plist, but with limited power/performance to save battery, and it can be potentially be killed by the system.

Not sure about it but I think connection is impossible when phone is locked. You can only restore previous connections.

There's more info about background bluetooth operations [in here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1).

Comment: I would like to know how we can implement the state restoration. I always get nil for dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] in willrestorestate delegate method. Using restoration key when initialising central in app

Comment: Did you set the `CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey` when initializing your central?

Comment: Is this the right way to define the restoration key:  NSString *CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey = @"somestring";